# Proteins and Blood Acidification

Tags: human-biology, proteins, hematology

Is there evidence to suggest that excessive consumption of Whey, or similar proteins will lead to acidification of the blood?

Comment: Can you provide a source for this claim?

Comment: [Found a study on _cows_](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022030281827464)